# JFrame and JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm making a GUI, which allows me to choose one of few options, which have more options(buttons). I'm inexperienced at Java and have some problem with it.

Why `this.dispose()` doesn't open new `JPanel` after clicking `Button11`? How I can open new `JPanel` exactly `Panel11`? Could you give me some advice?

```
class Panel1 extends JPanel
{
private Frame frame;
private JButton backButton;
private JButton Button11;
private JButton Button12;
private JButton Button13;

public Panel1(Frame f)
{
frame=f;

setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
backButton=new JButton("Back");
Button11=new JButton("Z warunkami atmosferycznymi");
Button12=new JButton("Z kontrolą ruchu lotniczego");
Button13=new JButton("Z uszkodzeniem/awarią");

add(new JLabel("Podczas lotu"));
add(backButton);
add(Button11);
add(Button12);
add(Button13);

backButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    frame.back(); }
                              }
);

Button11.addActionListener( new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Panel11 panel = new Panel11();
    panel.setVisible(true);
    panel.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.dispose();
       }
}
);
    }
}

class Panel11 extends JPanel
{

private Frame frame;
private JButton backButton;

public Panel11(Frame f)
{
frame=f;

setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,500));
backButton=new JButton("Back");
add(new JLabel("Podczas rotacji"));
add(backButton);
backButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
                              {
                                @Override
                              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                                {
                                  frame.back();
                                }
                              }
 );  
}
}

class Frame extends JFrame
{

private JPanel main;
private JButton button1;
private Panel1 panel1;


public Frame()
{
super("Algorytm przydziału kodów opóźnień");

main=new JPanel();
main.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,200));
panel1=new Panel1(this);

button1=new JButton("Podczas lotu");
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                          {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                            {
                              update(panel1);
                            }
                          }
);

main.add(button1);

setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
add(main);
pack();
setResizable(true);
setVisible(true);
}

public void back()
{
update(main);
}

private void update(JPanel panel)
{
remove(panel1);
remove(main);
add(panel);
pack();
panel.setVisible(true);
setVisible(true);
}
}


public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
new Frame();
}
}
```

Comment: please clarify what you want to happen: do you want that when you click button11 then panel 11 will show up in the Jframe?

Comment: @MarrieteCowby12 Yes

Comment: Java **is not** Javascript! Use the tags correctly!, Then please indent your code correctly and post a valid [mcve], (i.e. Not your whole code, but a simple example) which demonstrates your issue and as short as possible so we can copy-paste it and see it in our pc

Comment: Please don't revert the changes, you're using Java, not Javascript! You still forgot to indent your code correctly

Answer (score 2):

Your error is because you're calling:

```
Panel11 panel = new Panel11();
```

Now, let's see the constructor(s) of `Panel11`:

```
public Panel11(Frame f)
public Panel11()
```

Do you find any difference? Yes I know, you never wrote `public Panel11()`, but it's there by default, so, you're calling it and it's empty, so, you need to pass a `Frame` reference to it, also make sure to change that to `JFrame` instead of `Frame`, because `Frame` belongs to AWT while `JFrame` belongs to Swing.

You would have spotted that with proper code indenting, next thing is, you're using multiple `JFrames`, see [The use of multiple JFrames, Good / Bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice) (BAD!), instead you might want to use a [`Card Layout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) or [Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

If that doesn't help, please post a valid [Minimal, Complete and Verfiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)